# Why am I getting a Referencing Error in my Laravel migration?

Tags: php, laravel, database-migration

I am creating a Laravel e-commerce site and I am following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0lo7vzO1Fto&list=PLEhEHUEU3x5oPTli631ZX9cxl6cU_sDaR&index=20&t=417s

I am on episode 18, where the Order table is created. I am struggling with the first section of it, creating the migrations. There are two create migration files:

1. 2020_07_10_134530_create_orders_table.php (creates the order table)
2. 2020_07_10_135517_create_order_product_table.php (creates the pivot table for the order and the product)

My 'create_orders_table.php' looks like this:

```php
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')
                ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('set null');
            $table->string('billing_email')->nullable();
            $table->string('billing_name')->nullable();
            $table->string('billing_address')->nullable();
            $table->string('billing_city')->nullable();
            $table->string('billing_province')->nullable();
            $table->string('billing_postalcode')->nullable();
            $table->string('billing_phone')->nullable();
            $table->string('billing_name_on_card')->nullable();
            $table->integer('billing_discount')->default(0);
            $table->string('billing_discount_code')->nullable();
            $table->integer('billing_subtotal');
            $table->integer('billing_tax');
            $table->integer('billing_total');
            $table->string('payment_gateway')->default('stripe');
            $table->boolean('shipped')->default(false);
            $table->string('error')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

And my 'create_order_product_table.php' looks like this:

```php
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('order_product', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('order_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('order_id')->references('id')
                ->on('orders')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('set null');

            $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')
                ->on('iamlushes')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('set null');

            $table->integer('quantity')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

When I execute the command:

```
php artisan migrate
```

I get the following error from the terminal:

```
rosscurrie@Rosss-Air JanVal % php artisan migrate
Migrating: 2020_07_10_134530_create_orders_table

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3780 Referencing column 'user_id' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint 'orders_user_id_foreign' are incompatible. (SQL: alter table `orders` add constraint `orders_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`) on delete set null on update cascade)

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:671
    667|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    668|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    669|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    670|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 671|             throw new QueryException(
    672|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    673|             );
    674|         }
    675| 

      +11 vendor frames 
  12  database/migrations/2020_07_10_134530_create_orders_table.php:38
      Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic("create")

      +22 vendor frames 
  35  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```

The main error seems to be:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3780 Referencing column 'user_id' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint 'orders_user_id_foreign' are incompatible. (SQL: alter table `orders` add constraint `orders_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`) on delete set null on update cascade)
```

And I think it is referring to this line of code on my 'create_orders_table.php' migration:

```php
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('set null');
```

I am unsure of how to fix this error, here is my '2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php' migration:

```php
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

And here is my products tables '2020_06_16_124046_create_iamlushes_table.php' migration:

```php
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('iamlushes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->string('fullname')->unique();
            $table->string('productLogo');
            $table->string('img')->unique();
            $table->text('description');
            $table->integer('price');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: I'm not 100%, but I would guess it's the `->nullable()` that causes issues in: `$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable()` since the referenced column (the primary key for the other table) isn't nullable. And the same for `$table->integer('order_id')->unsigned()->nullable();`. If one column has a foreign key to another column, they need to be identical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `$table->id();` in creating `users` table. It create a column of type unsinedBigInteger in database, but you are referring to this column in `orders` table as a `unsignedInteger` which makes a conflict.

You should use `unsignedBigInteger` as the type of column for `user_id` in `orders` table as below:

```
Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')
            ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('set null');
        
        ....your code
});
```

Comment: Yes, it can solve your problem. Another way is the updated code that I posted in the answer. Change the column of `user_id` in `orders` table.